# Cannot set Data Validation in Excel by using MATCH formula C#

Tags: c#, excel, validation, office-interop, excel-interop

After use MATCH formula to validationStr, my class went wrong.
Can anyone tell me why error happened?
ERROR:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

Thank you very much!

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string validationListStr = "=OFFSET($AB$12,1,MATCH($T$12,$AB$12:$AD$12,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET($AB$12,1,MATCH($T$12,$AB$12:$AD$12,0)-1,100,1)),1)";
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Validation.Delete();
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, Type.Missing, validationListStr, Type.Missing);
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

I set the formula to validation by hand in Excel. There was no problem.
However, I cannot set the formula by C#.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I would like to create a data validation for the range, not a formula.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong 'Missing' object is being passed to the Add function.

`System.Type.Missing`  needs to be changed to `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Validation.Add(
    XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
    XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, 
    Missing.Value, // <-
    validationListStr, 
    Missing.Value // <-
);
```